# Upgrade additional 8 gb RAM DDR3 with 4gb Ram

Tags: cpu, computer-science, memory

I have laptop which was already having RAM 4Gb DDR3 1600MHz 11CLk and
I found RAM 8Gb DDR3 1600MHz can I mix it together 11Clk?
as I see both have the same clock speed 11 and 1600Mhz just different sizes, can it impact my computer? or any concern I should have. while using it together

Thanks.

Comment: I voted to migrate this question to SuperUser, because it would fit there better.

Comment: since this is a laptop, I'm expecting that you only have two RAM slots. make sure one of them is free (1x4GB chip, instead of 2x2GB chips), to make sure you have room. If you only have two slots and have two chips, I recommend they be of the same size, speed, timings, and voltage. personally, I'd either get 2x new 4GB chips and just replace what is already there, or get 2x 8GB chips. mixing 4GB and 8GB will probably work, but the RAM will run in single channel mode.

Comment: @FrankThomas Some laptops have RAM chips soldered onto the motherboard + single additional slot.

Answer (score 1):

It should work. You'll get 12 GB of RAM in total, but you won't benefit from dual channel - it works only if both modules have the same capacity. Since this is a DDR3 system the advantage of dual channel is relatively small and it's probably worth sacrificing for additional 4 GB. Some DDR4 systems have sigificant boosts from dual channel configurations and you'd have to run benchmarks and decide if it makes sense for you, but here I'd go for it.